# Using chrome developer tools Xpath to find correct child div id to target with a click function using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to target a specific div using jquery and the nth child selector. The code I am trying to manipulate is generated by a drag and drop cms so I cannot add id's to the elements. Another problem is all the classes are the same. I have managed to apply some ids to some of the divs but the little jquery script I have used won't add id's to the hidden elements that show on hover/click depending on device.

Here is the little script I have used to add id's do some of the divs, if any one knows how to make this apply id's to all the divs with .tcElement as a class that would work to:

```
$(".tcElement").each(function(i){
    $(this).attr('id', 'id_'+(i+1));
});
```

My question is how would I select and add a click event to a div with the xpath:
//*[@id="id_32"]/div/div/div[2]/div

Here is the jquery I am using:

```
$("#id_32 > div:nth-child(4)").click(function(e) {
              $("#tab-2").click();
              e.preventDefault();
        });
});
```

Here is the code output by the system:

[image: Screen shot of html]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this type of approach if very easy to break on the slightest change in HTML, you can use

```
$('#id_32 > div > div > div:eq(1) > div').click(...);
```

But be sure that the those div elements are not dynamically created/added or the above code will not work..

Comment: Hi, they are created by some drag and drop tool that outputs via a javascript viewer. Will that prevent it from working, I have had success with the about code

Comment: if they are created before you run the above code then no problem will occur.